# Custom prefix discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

Alright, so I am soooo confused. When I do my command "prefix", I get this error
return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: 'server.id'
Here's all code I got:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
   with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
       prefixes = json.load(f)

   prefixes[str(guild.id)] = ['s!', 'S!']
   with open('prefixes.json','w') as f:
       json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
   with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
       prefixes = json.load(f)

   prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

   prefixes[str(guild.id)] = ['s!', 'S!']
   with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

Command:

```
@client.command()
async def prefix(ctx, *, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send(f'Prefix set to: **"{prefix}"**')
```

also this piece of code:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
   with open('prefixes.json','r') as f:
       prefixes = json.load(f)

   return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

Please help me!

Comment: Also, it took me hours to post this

Comment: Oh yeah, I followed tutorial from Lucas aswell.

Answer (score 0):

nvm got answer:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open(....) as ...:
        prefixes = json.load(...)

    try: 
        # this will error if the guildid is not in the json
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
    except:
        # this code will run if the stuff in the if errors
        # here you need to add the guildid with your default prefix to the json
        # the code is pretty similar to what you have in your on_guild_join event, youll just need to change some stuff, like how to get the current guild

        # when you did that then do what you had in the try like this:
        # it shouldnt error now cause the guildid is now in the json 
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

Thank you for trying to help :D (lol)